# Publisher could not be verified while opening an exe from UNC path

Tags: vb6, publisher

I am getting the error "Publisher could not be verified. Are you sure you want to run this software" while opening an exe from UNC path. when I am trying to open an exe from UNC path (\abcserver\apps). There were two possible solutions but didn't work as I want.

This is an application accessing by 50+ people from the network share. As per the given solutions on the forums, I've added the intranet security to the zone with all options on.

(------Open Internet Explorer | Tools | Internet Options | Security
selected Local Intranet | Sites
Check all of the three selection boxes.
Now add the server as: \abcserver------)

But we don't want each and every user to add the security on their local machines. Anyway added the same to \abcserver as well. Is there a way to fix this more efficiently?

Thanks you.

Comment: Programs need to be installed on the systems that run them.  There are many pitfalls involved in running from a remote share.

Answer (score -1):

The warning is because your EXE is not digitally signed.

You can either

- Copy the EXE locally (maybe create an install program?)
- Change the user's security settings so there's no warning (you've found out about this already). You might be able to automate this, to reduce the user pain & chance of error.
- Sign the EXE. More details [here (general)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252226/signing-a-windows-exe-file) and [here (VB6-specific)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13980813/vb6-and-pfx-code-signing). Nb you will have to buy a certificate. Self-signing won't remove the security warning AFAIK unless perhaps you change the security settings to trust the certificate & it sounds like you're trying to avoid that.

Answer (score -1):

Worked for me ... 
Move the exe file to a non-ntfs volume (e.g. a USB flash drive (FAT)), then move it back again.

IT seems to be something to do with an NTFS property in the .exe file, which FAT does not have. So moving to a FAT drive removes it, and when moved back the propoerty is gone!.

See https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/fc98080e-db2a-463f-a3a0-372acb3b6eab/disable-the-publisher-could-not-be-verified-for-a-certain-application?forum=windowssecurity